# Doxygen 1.8.5: (1) How to properly process *.hh C++ files. (2) How to use multiple patterns with FILE_PATTERNS

Tags: doxygen

I have two problems with Doxygen 1.8.5.

I'm running Doxygen by using a dconfig file.

(1) I am forced to use *.cpp, *.h, *.hh, *.inc, and *.f separately when setting FILE_PATTERNS in the dconfig file. Otherwise, I get only the *.f files in the html output since *.f is the last pattern on the list.

Unless you have a solution, I can live with 5 different dconfig files.

(2) But, doxygen hangs at "Computing member relations..." when I use *.hh in a separate file. There's no output at all. (Doxgen seems to find the .hh files because the output to the screen shows them.)

I have to use Doxygen version 1.8.5. I also can't use Doxywizard.

In a separate file, I tried using only *.hh and putting an extra comma after *.hh. This allowed Doxygen to run to completion, but the outputted index.html file had none of the information about any of the .hh files.

Thank you,

Comment: This format doesn't work well with multiple questions on one page. Stick to one at a time, and see the [tour] and [ask] for more tips on getting the most out of the site.

Comment: Doxygen 1.8.5 is from August 23, 2013, the current version is 1.9.7 (released yesterday Mai 18, 2023) so please check with the new version.

Comment: What is a "dconfig" file? Doxygen configuration file maybe? You can specify multiple patterns either on one line or by means of `FILE_PATTERN +=`. About point 2 this might have been a problem in the 1.8.5 version, so please update!

Comment: The "FILE_PATTERN +=" does not work. The dconfig file is the only argument that I pass to doxygen when I run it. So, when I run doxygen, I type: doxygen dconfig. The name of the dconfig file can be whatever you want. I also tried an empty FILE_PATTERN line, but doxygen would hang processing the .hh files. As the original post says, I have to use version 1.8.5 of Doxygen!

Comment: Regarding question (1): You could try to give us more information by editing your question and adding the config file that you used and that didn't work as expected.

Comment: The "dconfig" file is produced by doxygen when I run the following command: doxygen -g dconfig.

Comment: The only things that I modify from the dconfig file produced by doxygen 1.8.5 is the following: FILE_PATTERNS = *.hh and RECURSIVE = YES. When I run that, it hangs. Just before the FILE_PATTERNS tag, the dconfig file states that *.hh is a legitimate pattern to use.

Comment: If I don't add YES to "RECURSIVE =" doxygen runs to completion. But, the resulting index.html file is basically blank. The html page says My Project, Main Page, My Project Documentation, and Generated by doxygen 1.8.5. There are no links on the page that tell me anything about the code.

Comment: If you have doxygen 1.8.5 installed on your computer you can create my dconfig file. If you do not have doxgen 1.8.5 then you probably do not have the environment that I have, and you might not be able to solve the problem. Even though you might get some ideas by comparing my dconfig file against yours, the owner of my laptop will not allow me to post the entire dconfig file.

Comment: Do you think it's worth trying to EXCLUDE one, then two, then three, ..., then n of the *.hh files? There's hundreds. Can I exclude directories?